# Dagger 2 - two instances of the same View model are created

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger

I’m trying to implement Dagger 2 in my Android app, and got stuck it this problem:
The ActivityModels I use are created with an implementation of ViewModelProvider.Factory (as the [example here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)). I attach the model to the activity by injecting the factory and calling:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyActivityViewModel.class);
```

In another part of the app I’m trying to use a Command class to make changes to the model, so I injected MyActivityViewModel directly to it.

```
@Inject
public SearchCommand(MyActivityViewModel viewModel) {
    super(viewModel);
}
```

The problem: The injected ViewModel is a new instance of the view model, different than the one instantiated in the Activity. Whatever I try I don’t manage to solve that… Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Dagger 2 scopes correctly?

Comment: Not sure, since I don't really know how to use these... Just copying code.
Any place recommended to learn Dagger?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but following the code of ViewModelProviders, I changed just for the Fragment the first parameter of `ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)` by getActivity(). The resulting line is

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(MyActivityViewModel.class);
```